# How to add an element in a HTML document using pure javascript at particular position of the document

Tags: javascript, html

I know I can add an element using javascript by:

`document.createElement('input');`

But I want to add it in a particular position of the document, like after the `submit` button, or after the `textfield`

Comment: The function `.addElement` does not exist in the DOM afaik.

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML. This might also help: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry createElement

Comment: or look at this http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

`s` is the element you want to put the new element after.

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var newNode = document.createElement("input");

s.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, s.nextSibling);
```

This will place the new `input` after the current `input`.

Alternatively:

```
var f = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
var newNode = document.createElement("input");
f.appendChild(newNode);
```

Comment: Where will the element be created in your second way

Comment: @govindo It will be at the end of `form` element, just before `</form>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a node with one of the GetElementsBy functions, and then append new DOM Elements with Node.appendChild().

Comment: `Node.appendChild()` will insert the element at the end of `Node`. This might not be sufficient if the OP wants to insert the element immediately after an existing element on the page.

Comment: If you select for the proper element (choosing proper classes and ids), this shouldn't really be a problem. You can then pick out exactly which elements to place after.

Comment: What to do if I want to add an element front of all the elements

Comment: You would do something along the lines of this example:
someParentObject.appendChild(someChildObject,someParentObject.firstChild);